# Failed to customize listview adapter

Tags: java, android

I have a table(sql table 2008),in that table i have two column(name and date),my attention is to fetch data and display those data into listview.As i early mention there are two indivisual column,after doing some research i learned that i need to customize my list view table into two different column and the display data in it here is my customize listview file

public class testlistviewAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    public testlistviewAdapter(Context context, String[] foods) {

        super(context, R.layout.testlistview,foods);
    }

@Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent ){
    LayoutInflater joyinflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView=joyinflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_adapter_file,parent,false);

    String singleFoodItem=getItem(position);
    TextView firstrow=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tx);
    TextView secondrow=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
    firstrow.setText(singleFoodItem);
    secondrow.setText(singleFoodItem);
     return customView;
    }
```

Mainactivity file's code like below

```
ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
                while(rs.next()){
                    String id=rs.getString("tm");
                    data.add(id);
                }
              String[] foods=data.toArray(new String[0]);
            ArrayAdapter joyAdapter=new testlistviewAdapter(this,foods);
             myOne.setAdapter(joyAdapter);
```

What i am doing wrong? And what change i have to make, if i want to create header for two column? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your custom adapter with your Data (Item Object inside the following Example).

```
    ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
    // data from the table
    ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, List<yourItem>);
    yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Your custom Adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
    }

    Item p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        TextView firstrow=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.tx);
        TextView secondrow (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
        firstrow.setText(singleFoodItem);
        secondrow.setText(singleFoodItem);


    }

    return v;
}}
```

Comment: Well,Just try your code it do exactly what i did before.